# Error when trying to execute command with sudo su - user -- command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sudo, aix

I am facing a problem when trying to execute a command using another user.

If I do this

```
sudo su - user
direct
```

Works perfectly

Now if I do this

```
sudo su - user -c direct
```

I face this error

```
-bash: direct: command not found
```

Does someone know what's happening? Thank you for your attention.

Comment: What is `direct`? Is it a command found in the PATH or is it a shell function/alias?

Comment: direct is a IBM tool to transfer files between servers. How can I see if its in the path?

Comment: In the interactive `user`'s shell, what does `type -a direct` show?

Comment: direct is /connect/ndm/bin/direc

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=s-su-command

Comment: Huuuum... Should I use su instead of sudo su?

Comment: Also try `sudo su - user -c env` to see what the user's environment is.

Comment: If you leave out `sudo`, you'll be asked to enter user's password.

Comment: Oh, got it. When I run sudo su - user -c env this appears: DMDIR=/etc/objrepos\r\nLANG=en_US\r\nTZ=America/Sao_Paulo\r\nAUTHSTATE=files\r\nUSER=connect\r\nPWD=/home/connect\r\nHOME=/home/connect\r\nCLCMD_PASSTHRU=1\r\nLOCPATH=/usr/lib/nls/loc\r\nSHELL=/usr/bin/bash\r\nTERM=vt100\r\nSHLVL=1\r\nLC__FASTMSG=true\r\nLOGNAME=connect\r\nPATH=/usr/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bin/X11:/sbin:/usr/java8_64/jre/bin:/usr/java8_64/bin\r\nLOGIN=connect\r\n_=/usr/bin/env\r\nNLSPATH=/usr/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N:/usr/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat:/usr/lib/nls/msg/%l.%c/%N:/usr/lib/nls/msg/%l.%c/%N.cat\r\n

Comment: Try `sudo -E su user -c env` to see if that preserves **your** environment.

Comment: I replaced the ips with * and the first user with original_user 
D=/usr/bin/su connect -c env\r\nUSER=root\r\nPWD=/home/original_user\r\nHOME=/\r\nSSH_CLIENT=****** 22\r\nSUDO_USER=original_user\r\nCLCMD_PASSTHRU=1\r\nSSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1\r\nLOCPATH=/usr/lib/nls/loc\r\nSUDO_UID=*********\r\nMAIL=/var/spool/mail/original_user\r\nTERM=vt100\r\nSHELL=/bin/sh\r\nSHLVL=1\r\nLC__FASTMSG=true\r\nLOGNAME=root\r\nPATH=/usr/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bin/X11:/sbin:/usr/java8_64/jre/bin:/usr/java8_64/bin\r\nLOGIN=connect\r\n')

Comment: well, looks like you need to specify the full path on to `direct`

Comment: Huuuuum... sorry for the late answer. So, the fullpath is /user/ndm/bin/direct. How can I run this using another user?

Comment: sudo su - user -c /user/ndm/bin/direct

Comment: It worked but now I am facing another error

XCLC001I  Return Code: 8  Feedback: 0
          Missing CLI environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need `su` in the command at all (what your `sudo su - user` does is to use `sudo` to jump to `root` with full privileges, and then use `su` to downgrade to the account called `user`. You might as well just jump straight to `user` with `sudo`).

One of these lines will work, depending on how `/connect/ndm/bin` has been added to your `$PATH`. Use the first one that works:

```
sudo -u user direct
sudo -iu user direct
sudo -Hiu user direct
```

The first variant runs `direct` as user `user`. The second variant also tells the target shell to run in "interactive" mode, which means for `bash` it would execute `.bash_profile` or `.profile`, setting up the environment (`$PATH`, etc.). The final version also forces the `$HOME` variable to be set for the target user account too. With some configurations this is done automatically by `sudo` but I included it here anyway "just in case".

Comment: Thank you so much! The second and third options worked for me, but, may you explain to me what they are really doing?

Comment: @AntonioCosta I've added a paragraph of explanation. I hope it's sufficiently understandable

Answer (score 1):

`sudo su - user` will load the profile startup files, which probably set the `PATH` to the `direct` command.

When you use `-c`, the `direct` command can't be found.

One solutions would be to specify the full path to the binary:

`sudo su - user -c /full/path/to/direct`

To find this path, use `command -v` or `which` from the shell able to find it:

```
sudo su - user
command -v direct
```

Comment: Got it! In my case, I have tried using the full path of direct but I faced another error from direct application.