# Execute sudo su - user on a ssh session

Tags: ssh, sudo, remote-access, remote, aix

I need to execute sudo su - user on a ssh connection, because sudo su - user -c it's not available in the servers. Is there a way to do it? Thank you for the attention.

Comment: have you tried sudo -i followed by su <user>?  The first one makes you root which might? let you use the second su command?  Stupid but possible guess.

Comment: Simpler than @SeñorCMasMas 's answer is `sudo -i -u user`. Does `sudo -l` give any insight on what commands you have available to you?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I have tried both things, but they both don`t work for me. Yes, sudo -l give me the commands that y user can execute.

Comment: I am doing this because there is a command that I can`t run using ```sudo su - user -c```, now, if I do ```sudo su - user``` and execute the command it works perfectly.

Comment: How can I send commands after ```sudo -i -u user```?

Comment: I would look at [the answer I've given you](https://superuser.com/a/1744962/332907) on your earlier question that's _almost identical_ to this one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when trying to execute command with sudo su - user -- command](https://superuser.com/questions/1744469/error-when-trying-to-execute-command-with-sudo-su-user-command)